# MarkLogic: Application Builder

Tags: web-applications, marklogic

I am stuck on how to use application builder of MarkLogic.
How do I create index in MarkLogic & link them to be included in the Application to be used as Fields for Search.

I have uploaded a sample data RDF using MLCP, created database in MarkLogic.
Then using the Application Builder, I wanted to make a Search Engine 
Application. 
In Application Builder the database is selected properly, but the Range index, how to define it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create any index from within the MarkLogic admin console on port 8001. Browse to your database in the sidebar on the left, and you'll see all the available types of indexes.

The docs contain a [walkthrough on creating an element range index](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_51346).

Alternatively, you can create certain indexes from within Application Builder itself. Begin by selecting your database and clicking *Configure*. As advised by @dave-cassel, you'll want to use the *Resample* button to detect the new index(es).